# How to get PhpStorm to autocomplete facades in blade-files

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade, phpdoc

When using `@if (Auth::check())`, PhpStorm doesn't recognize the `Auth`.

How do I tell PhpStorm that `Auth` is `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`?

Tested:

```
@php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
/** @var \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth Auth */
class Auth extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth {}
@endphp

@use(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth)
```

neither worked, still get "Undefined Class Auth"

Edit 1:

the `class Auth extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth {}` line works if it's in another file, for example, the "_ide_helper.php", having it inside the blade file doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDE won't recognize methods accessed via the facade. `laravel-ide-helper` is a popular package that solves this problem. It generates a custom helper file that the IDE understands. This is not a complete solution but it covers most of laravel classes and helps with autocompletion. Here are your options.

1. Download and drop the latest `_ide_helper.php` file for laravel into your project from https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822
2. Install the `laravel-ide-helper` package and let it generate a helper file on the fly. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

I'd personally suggest installing the package.

Comment: the method isn't the problem, it dosn't reconize the class at all, when it's inside blade.

Comment: @PugganSe i use ide-helper and phpstorm and i never have to worry about that. The `Auth` face is registered to `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`. So normally you would use `\Auth::check()` or `Auth::check()` with `use Auth` in your controller. But the views default to the root namespace so using `Auth::check()` alone would work even if your IDE complains. But with the helper file it won't because it creates a class that's recognisable by the IDE. Check this out https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822#file-_ide_helper-php-L13261

Comment: @PugganSe Works fine here with Laravel Helper: http://postimg.org/image/ndzheeg77/

Comment: @PugganSe the best part is that ide-helper gives you autocompletion for facades. Check this out https://puu.sh/w7xqd/11a59c953a.png

Comment: As ide-helper died with fatal errors when trying it in the dev envirement, I tried to fix the few fasades manualy, but compy the code to an envirement that had php7, and then copy the ide-helper-file back, worked ok.

Answer (score 1):

To get the right class use `@if (\Auth::check())`!

Comment: Still Undefined Class

Comment: Try: `use \Auth;`

Comment: Undefined class at that use-row